# IPython kernel development: kernel_info_reply is ineffective on code highlighting

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

When I was testing a custom IPython kernel for Spark (https://github.com/tribbloid/ISpark)

The code highlighting and comment line shortcut don't work despite that both block metadata and websocket communication shows that kernel_info_reply is received:

metadata:

```
{ 
  "kernelspec": { 
    "name": "spark", 
    "display_name": "ISpark", 
    "language": "Scala" 
  }, 
  "language_info": { 
    "mimetype": "text/x-scala", 
    "file_extension": "scala", 
    "version": "2.10.4", 
    "name": "Scala", 
    "codemirror_mode": "Scala" 
  } 
}
```

websocket message received:

```
{"parent_header": {"username": "username", "session": "1E1A0C0BD7B848D5874427164D5A6407", "version": "5.0", "msg_id": "393B1AED65C34EDA9DB6B0CACAB1DA03", "msg_type": "kernel_info_request"}, "msg_type": "kernel_info_reply", "msg_id": "44558c0a-5a49-469a-b55a-9032fa10ee5b", "content": {"implementation": "iSpark", "protocol_version": "5.0", "language_info": {"mimetype": "text/x-scala", "file_extension": "scala", "version": "2.10.4", "name": "Scala", "codemirror_mode": "Scala"}, "implementation_version": "0.2.0", "banner": "welcome to Spark version 1.3.1"}, "header": {"username": "username", "session": "1E1A0C0BD7B848D5874427164D5A6407", "version": "5.0", "msg_id": "44558c0a-5a49-469a-b55a-9032fa10ee5b", "msg_type": "kernel_info_reply"}, "channel": "shell", "buffers": [], "metadata": {}}
```

I also notice an anomaly that used to be harmless, a warning was logged when the kernel is launching:

[W 15:07:03.310 NotebookApp] Timeout waiting for kernel_info reply from 9ce0a466-2bbb-48c6-99a1-5211a207f81a

It may be related to https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/6793, but according to the issue tracker such problem won't exist as long as the metadata is correct.

What are the likely causes of this error and how to fix it?